# Inline Query to Procedure

Tags: asp.net, .net, oracle, plsqldeveloper

How do i write a procedure for login query in .net :

```
StringBuilder sql;
  sql = new StringBuilder("Select User From Login_user ");
  sql.Append(" Where User_Name_upper = '" + strUserName.ToString().ToUpper() + "'");
  OracleCommand cmdUserDetails = new OracleCommand(sql.ToString(), conSODEV);
```

Comment: Your code is prone to SQL injection. How about consider using store procedure or parameters?

Comment: @Win that's precisely what he's asking.

Answer (score 1):

It would be something *like* this:

```
create or replace procedure usernameExists (username in VARCHAR ) is      
    l_user user_tables.owner%type;
BEGIN
    Select User 
    into l_user
    From Login_user 
    where User_Name_upper = upper(username);
EXCEPTION
    when NO_DATA_FOUND then
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'User does not exist!');
END;
```

Then you'd call it like this:

```
 OracleCommand cmdUserDetails = new OracleCommand("usernameExists", conSODEV);
 cmdUserDetails.Parameters.AddWithValue("username",username_variable);
 IDataReader reader = cmdUserDetails.ExecuteReader();
```

**Note 1**: I am not an Oracle developer but it should be VERY close to that.

**Note 2**: Above procedure will simply return records if the username exists. You mentioned a "login procedure" but your original query does not have any code that checks for password as well. If you want to implement a "login procedure" then you need to match both, username and password in the select statement and you also need to make sure that you check for case sensitivity properly.

Comment: PROCEDURE usernameExists( username IN  VARCHAR2
      ) AS
          
          l_user VARCHAR2(20);
          
  BEGIN
  
      Select USER  INTO l_user
    From Login_user
    where User_Name_upper = upper(username);
 EXCEPTION
    when NO_DATA_FOUND then
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'User does not exist!');

END PortalLogin;

Comment: in .net: cmd.CommandText = "usernameExists ";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               
                cmd.Parameters.Add("username", OracleType.VarChar, 20, strUserName.ToString().ToUpper()); strUSER__T = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                return strUSER__T;